# Unable to call method from one class to another class while using ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I know how to call a method of one class to another class. However This time its not working for me and its just driving me nuts. Below is my code

**MenuPageCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MenuPageViewController;
@interface MenuPageCell : UITableViewCell{
 NSInteger   m_cellIndex;
    MenuPageViewController   *m_parentViewController;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger      m_cellIndex;
@property(nonatomic, strong) MenuPageViewController   *m_parentViewController;
-(IBAction) addToCart;

@end
```

**MenuPAgeCell.m**

```
#import "MenuPageCell.h"
#import "MenuPageViewController.h"
@implementation MenuPageCell

@synthesize m_cellIndex;
@synthesize m_parentViewController;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
-(IBAction) addToCart
{
    NSLog(@"Add To cart = %d",self.m_cellIndex);

    [m_parentViewController addItemToCart:self.m_cellIndex];
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

**MenuPageViewController.m**

```
-(void) addItemToCart:(NSInteger)aIndexItem
{
   NSLog(@"In Add to Cart method");
}
```

Now, This code works fine for non ARC Used project but its not working for me. I know it should be silly mistake but I'm unable to figure it out.

Thanks & regards

Mayur

Comment: I beleave m_parentViewController is nil when you sent AddToCart message to it

Comment: Guys For the above code I missed this single line of code and cudn't track it. I forgot to set my parent class in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of table like this.[cell setM_parentViewController:self];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing ViewController from a cell is a design flaw, consider using delegate instead. But if you really need the ViewController property, make it `weak` instead of `strong` because currently you end up with retain cycle.

```
@protocol MenuPageCellDelegate<NSObject>
- (void)addItemToCart:(NSInteger)aIndexItem;
@end

@interface MenuPageCell : UITableViewCell {
    NSInteger m_cellIndex;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger m_cellIndex;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<MenuPageCellDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction) addToCart;

@end

@implementation MenuPageCell
...
-(IBAction) addToCart
{
    NSLog(@"Add To cart = %d",self.m_cellIndex);

    if ([self.delegate responsToSelector:@selector(addItemToCart:)]) {
        [self.delegate addItemToCart:self.m_cellIndex];
    }
}
...
@end
```

Add `MenuPageCellDelegate` to the list of implemented protocols of `MenuPageViewController` and (if it's implementing `UITableViewDataSource` protocol) in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method write `cell.delegate = self;` instead of `cell.m_parentViewController = self;`

Answer (score 0):

initialize your `m_parentViewController` in `viewDidLoad` method.

such like

```
m_parentViewController = [[yourViewControllerName alloc] init];
```

and then call

```
[m_parentViewController addItemToCart:self.m_cellIndex];
```

Comment: as I said,I know How to call a method like that.. But I don't want to initialise object at this point. And the above code is working fine in  one of my old projects. Thanks though

Comment: @MayurCM - but what is problem with `initialise object` ?? you can not call method without doing that :(

Comment: it's a property declared in .h, so could be initialized/assigned outside. Have you printed m_parentViewController in console to make sure it's not nil?

Answer (score 0):

in the cellforrow method of your tableview add a selector to the cell button and also set the tag equal to the indexpath. now in the selector just distinguish between the  different cells with the help of sender.tag.